# Trigger for tower game in C# for wp7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I was thinking about building a [tower defence game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_defense) and was trying to find the best way 
to find the shortest path to the other side.

How can i do this?

---

I know I need to re evaluate the path on every move due to people adding more towers.
I am thinking I need to use visualtreehelper to find what is in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be better asked at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

You don't need to re-calculate the path all the time, only when a tower is created or destroyed.

The A* algorithm would be commonly used, there are [many samples around](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=A*%20path%20finding%20c#&meta=). Making your game tile-based would simplify its use, as each tile would be a node, and it's trivial to work out the connections (i.e. up/down/left/right, providing the node isn't blocked).

Comment: Here is the link that has my info I was looking for .  http://www.dotnetperls.com/pathfinding